# What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?

Tags: c#, ipc

I want to create a communication between a parent and a child process, both written in C#.

It should be asynchronous, event-driven.

I don't want to run a thread in every process to handle the very rare communication.

What is the best solution for it?

Comment: I've done an article on my blog of a really simple example of inter-process communication using Named Pipes in WCF. [https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/](https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/)

Comment: Are you talking about asynchronous processes or asynchronous communication? The first one can be done with WCF or WebServices or anything over tcp or pipes or anything. But asynchronous communication requires a queuing technology like MSMQ or Azure Service Bus or RabbitMQ.

Comment: [Related: What is the easiest way to do inter process communication in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802475/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-do-inter-process-communication-in-c)

Comment: @RiainMcAtamney -- link died. :(

Answer (score 56):

[Anonymous pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication).

Use Asynchronous operations with BeginRead/BeginWrite and AsyncCallback.

Answer (score 23):

If your processes in same computer, you can simply use **stdio**.

This is my usage, a web page screenshooter:

```
var jobProcess = new Process();

jobProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
jobProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "job";

jobProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
jobProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

jobProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
jobProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
jobProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

// Just Console.WriteLine it.
jobProcess.ErrorDataReceived += jp_ErrorDataReceived;

jobProcess.Start();

jobProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

try
{
    jobProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(url);
    var buf = new byte[int.Parse(jobProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine())];
    jobProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    return Deserz<Bitmap>(buf);
}
finally
{
    if (jobProcess.HasExited == false)
        jobProcess.Kill();
}
```

Detect args on Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 1 && args[0]=="job")
    {
        //because stdout has been used by send back, our logs should put to stderr
        Log.SetLogOutput(Console.Error); 

        try
        {
            var url = Console.ReadLine();
            var bmp = new WebPageShooterCr().Shoot(url);
            var buf = Serz(bmp);
            Console.WriteLine(buf.Length);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            using (var o = Console.OpenStandardOutput())
                o.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.E("Err:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Won't work however if the target process needs to have a GUI, i.e. if `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` is `true`. In that case you cannot redirect standard output and error.

Comment: @JayCroghan i don't think you can use it when it has a GUI. At least when the client process is launched from a web application.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using the Windows Communication Foundation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation

You can pass objects back and forth, use a variety of different protocols.  I would suggest using the binary tcp protocol.

Comment: ... so what's the complicated way then?

Comment: If WCF is the "simplest method", I really want to cry :P

Comment: @kizzx2 We're starting to get into WCF in quite a big way and once you've gone through the initial confusion WCF is really cool. I found this guy's simple implementation really useful http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39837

Comment: @CharlieAspinall if 5 pages of C# and XML is simple. I really really want to cry.

Comment: WCF is a web service wrapper for REST. The question relates to Windows processes.

Answer (score 7):

Named pipes on WCF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Following are the ways to do Inter Process Communication asynchronously:

1. Anonymous Pipes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeserverstream?view=net-5.0
2. Named Pipes https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1179195/Full-Duplex-Asynchronous-Read-Write-with-Named-Pip
3. Sockets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example
4. Shared memory

Answer (score 3):

There's also [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-clients-and-servers).

There are technicalities, but I'd say the advantage is that you'll be able to call methods that you can define.

MSDN offers C# COM interop tutorials. Please search because these links do change.

To get started rightaway go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092553/turn-a-simple-c-sharp-dll-into-a-com-interop-component)...

Answer (score 3):

The *easiest* solution in C# for inter-process communication when security is not a concern and given your constraints (two C# processes on the same machine) is the Remoting API. Now Remoting is a legacy technology (not the same as deprecated) and not encouraged for use in new projects, but it does work well and does not require a lot of pomp and circumstance to get working.

There is an [excellent article on MSDN for using the class `IpcChannel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) from the Remoting framework (credit to [Greg Beech for the find here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802572/184528)) for setting up a simple remoting server and client.

I Would suggest trying this approach first, and then try to port your code to WCF (Windows Communication Framework). Which has several advantages (better security, cross-platform), but is necessarily more complex. Luckily MSDN has a [very good article for porting code from Remoting to WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/migrating-from-net-remoting-to-wcf).

If you want to dive in right away with [WCF there is a great tutorial here](https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/).

Answer (score 3):

If possible, it's just easier to make a shared file!

```
//out
File.AppendAllText("sharedFile.txt", "payload text here");
// in
File.ReadAllText("sharedFile.txt");
```

Comment: Or you could bang two rocks together... this method would require polling and extra error handling around locked files etc. and is NOT event driven.  Sure, it could work, but...

Comment: I think this is not such a bad answer. .NET supplies a very neat class to make this event driven: https://stackoverflow.com/a/721743

Comment: @LordWabbit It could work, and it does. The question is not about the "best" method, but the "simplest". This is one of the simplest methods imaginable. And this answer may not be the best, but surely is far more useful than your rocks-banging analogy, or, in fact, your whole condescending comment.

Answer (score 2):

There's also MSMQ (Microsoft Message Queueing) which can operate across networks as well as on a local computer. Although there are better ways to communicate it's worth looking into: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx