# How to share data between two instances of the same application in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro)

I need to develop a windows application in C# where two instances of the application will run. One will be operational and another will be on standby. If for any reason first instance will hang or stop working, the second instance should start operation.

Comment: Please read this [Check list](http://tinyurl.com/so-list) when posting a question.

Comment: @Azodious, I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @zmbq: the question needs more clarity and that's why added possible at the start. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use a database. The first instance stores everything in the database (and uses transactions if possible, to make sure the data is always in a consistent state). The second instance can then wake up and read the latest state from the database.

Comment: +1. To complete - have failover DB server in standby.

Comment: Wait, don't we just do everything in the almighty cloud these days?

Comment: We do, which is why you need a second instance in a *second cloud*...

Answer (score 1):

However you handle the data is one thing.

A more common way to do what you're trying is having a *watchdog* process. He is **not** a second instance of the same process. Instead, he listens to a heartbeat, or something else on the first process. If he decides that the first process is dead, he then can kill it / start a new instance, etc.