# C# on doubleclick open app and paste field data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, double-click

Question, I have two applications. I set a doubleclick event on the first one that opens app called employees. I want to copy the data in label1 from application one onto the txtone of the second application and hit the run button.

This is the code i have for opening the 2nd app but i cant figure out how to compile the rest. Any suggestions would be great!

```
Process Employees= new Process();           
Employees.StartInfo.FileName = "F:\\Employees.exe";     
Employees.Start();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data with arguments like this:

```
Employees.StartInfo.Arguments = your_argument
```

In your employee app you can retrieve the data in the Program class Main method with the args parameter.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new FormMain(args)); //pass arguments to main form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doesn't sound like a particularly neat solution however have you considered adding arguments to the start

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via multiple ways. Possible options are

1. [MSMQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5830/Using-MSMQ-from-C)
2. [Remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example)
3. [FileWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)
4. [Arguement Passing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)