# call a console application

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

What is the code to call a console application within a WPF? I have an application in WPF you need:

1. call a console application;
2. the console application closes the WPF
3. The console application again calls WPF and close console application.

This is necessary because I am doing a system where updates to the application must close the files to copy.

For close application WPF I am using the following:

```
Process wpfProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MainWindow.exe").First();
wpfProc.Kill();
```

return in console application:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence sontains no elements
    at System.Link.Enumerable.First[TSource]<IEnumerable'1 source>
    at Updater.Program.Main<String[] args> in d:\endereçodoUpdater\Program.cs:line 17
```

in line 17 have the following:

```
Process wpfProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MainWindow").First();
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `updates to the application` - Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use ClickOnce.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help. For some particular reason, can not use ClickOnce. I need to create a project update for a particular application where the main application should be closed for some files are copied to the installation directory. Soon after the main application will be reopened.

Comment: I've written plenty of installers where ClickOnce isn't an option and needed to do something very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with Process.Start:

```
Process myProc = Process.Start("MyConsoleApp.exe");

//Close gracefully
Application.Exit();
```

In MyConsoleApp.exe, you would need to use GetProcessByName to kill your WPF app, and then Process.Start again to restart it:

```
Process wpfProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyWpfApp.exe").First();

//If you want to directly kill it
wpfProc.Kill();

//Or be nice and let it kill itself
wpfProc.WaitForExit();

//Do stuff
Process.Start("MyWpfApp.exe");
```

System.Diagnostics.Process on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Diagnostics.Process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Eww. No need to `Kill`, just wait for the process to start then end the application. In the console wait for the other to not be running.

Comment: [The interprocess communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro) might also be useful, in case you don't want just to kill app but do it in some smart way.

Comment: @crashmstr, Edited to include a "nicer" way of doing it. The OP requested that the console app kill the WPF app directly though (I agree that waiting for exit is a better approach btw)

Comment: @LordTakkera I don't think they really had an idea it could be done this way, and it was more of a "flow" of what needed to happen (i.e. the WPF app closes through *some* means). But I'm willing to up-vote now :)