# How to send data / values to the embedded exe applications from the Host WPF

Tags: wpf

How to send or pass data or values to the embedded Exe application from the Host WPF Application ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: It is InterProcessCommunication. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro

Comment: I have embedded unity 3D game exe in WPF application and now need to pass data from WPF to unity to operate. Don't want to use any input device.