# Button click in ASP.NET invoke Windows Form method C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-services

I am working on finger and face identify machines which use zkemKeeper.dll class library. It only works on desktop application. I have synchronized faces between the devices on desktop. I need to invoke that method in ASP.NET button click. Kindly suggest me what I have to do in this scenario?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro) and [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Listen on a port in your desktop application by using Tcp Listener. Send http request to that application when you click ASP.Net button.

Answer (score 1):

```
public zkemkeeper.CZKEM zkemKeeper = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();//initializing dll

private bool bIsConnected = false;//the boolean value identifies whether the device is connected
//Initializing bisconnected to connect the device
bool bIsConnected = zkemKeeper.Connect_Net(txtip.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtport.Text));
 private void btnDownLoadFace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string sUserID = "";
    string sName = "";
    string sPassword = "";
    int iPrivilege = 0;
    bool bEnabled = false;
    int iFaceIndex = 50;//the only possible parameter value
    string sTmpData = "";
    int iLength = 0;
    zkemKeeper.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);
        zkemKeeper.ReadAllUserID(iMachineNumber);//read all the user information to the memory

        while (zkemKeeper.SSR_GetAllUserInfo(iMachineNumber, out sUserID, out sName, out sPassword, out iPrivilege, out bEnabled))//get all the users' information from the memory
        {
            if (zkemKeeper.GetUserFaceStr(iMachineNumber, sUserID, iFaceIndex, ref sTmpData, ref iLength))//get the face templates from the memory
            {
                //save whatever data you want for eg:
               ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem();
                list.Text = sUserID;
                list.SubItems.Add(sName);
                list.SubItems.Add(sPassword);
                list.SubItems.Add(iPrivilege.ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(iFaceIndex.ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(sTmpData);
                list.SubItems.Add(iLength.ToString());
                if (bEnabled == true)
                {
                    list.SubItems.Add("true");
                }
                else
                {
                    list.SubItems.Add("false");
                }
                lvFace.Items.Add(list);//lv Face is a List View 
            }
        }
 zkemKeeper.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);
}
```