# Issue in synchronization of method when called from different application

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a class Library Application Called API. Inside which I have a method called SynchronizeMe.

```
 public class APIClass
    {
        object baton = new object();
        static int count = 0;
        public void SynchronizeMe()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                lock (baton)
                {
                    int temp = count;
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    count = temp + 1;

                    Console.WriteLine("Thread Id " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " Name:" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " incremented count to " + count);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }
```

I have two console Application Thread1 and Thread2. Both of them calling SynchronizeMe Method.
 Like

```
 API.APIClass apicall = new API.APIClass();
 apicall.SynchronizeMe();
```

When I run this I see Both of them printing count start from 1. That means it is not syncronized. Am I understanding the concept of multi threading something wrong? Or code has issue? Or Thread in same application can only be synchronized. If I want to synchronize this way what is the way?

I think both Thread1 and Thread2 has different Instance of APIClass so Synchronization not Possible. Is there some way out?

Comment: To clarify, do you have two separately running console applications that call the library, or two threads in a single console application?

Comment: @user783836 Two separately running console application.

Comment: @TBAG see my answer then

Answer (score 2):

In the case where you have two separate console applications, locks using the `lock` keyword are not shared between them - `lock` is local to the individual process.

If you want to lock across processes you need to use a `named mutex` instead.

See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/threading-with-mutex/.

For cross process locking with a mutex, see http://mikeperetz.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/cross-process-locking-using-named-mutex.html

Your code would look something like:

```
    public class APIClass
{
    private const string MutexName = "FAA9569-7DFE-4D6D-874D-19123FB16CBC-8739827-[SystemSpecicString]";
    private Mutex _globalMutex;
    private bool _owned = false;
    private int timeToWait = 1000;

    object baton = new object();
    static int count = 0;
    public void SynchronizeMe()
    {
        _globalMutex = new Mutex(true, MutexName, out _owned);
        while(true)
        {
            while (!_owned)
            {
                // did not get the mutex, wait for it.
                _owned = _globalMutex.WaitOne(timeToWait);
            }

            int temp = count;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            count = temp + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Thread Id " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " Name:" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " incremented count to " + count);
            // release the mutex
            _globalMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While the synchronization will work, it will still not use the same counter variable between processes.

Comment: @nvoigt fair point and its not clear from the OP if that is the goal or if it was just to understand cross process synchronization

Comment: @user783836 second thread is not able to acquire lock. Only thread1 is priniting value. second console gers nothing.

Comment: @TBAG this is because neither process ever yields the lock. Your code in the original question has the same problem. I have updated the code sample to yield the lock. Note however that, as @nvoigt pointed out, no variables (such as `count`) are shared across the processes. For that you'd need memory mapped files or similar.

Comment: @user783836 Previous code was printing in both consoles. Share count variable is not important for me.

Comment: @TBAG, yes, because they were running as totally isolated processes. Now, with the mutex, the process with the mutex will block the other unless the lock is yielded

Comment: @user783836 Getting following exception - Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code. System.ApplicationException

Answer (score 0):

Two processes (or rather two app domains) will load two *totally separate copies* of your library.

So not only will your `lock` only lock the copy of the calling assembly, your `count` variable will exist as two separate copies as well.

You can have process-agnostic synchronization with for example a [mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) but you still need to find a way to share that counter. That can be as simple as keeping it in a file or registry entry, or you could use a database. But if you want to keep it in memory, you will need to start a third process instead of loading a copy of each library into your existing processes. That means you will need [inter process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro).