# Is it possible to get info about the edited file chunk data?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, filestream

Process **A** and **B** both simultaneously open some data file and edit it's several data chunks. Each process uses `FileStream` and its `Lock()` and `Unlock()` methods. Thus, at the same time, one and the same piece of data can be edited only by process A or В but not by both simultaneously.

Is it possible to get the notification for **A** process when **B** process edited the file with detailed info about the position and length of the edited data chunk?

Some mechanism keeps track of the locking and unlocking. Perhaps the same mechanism can provide the information that interests me. I do not claim this, but I hope for such an opportunity is existing.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro

Comment: @bradbury9 no, my question is about other. I know how to send the data from one process to another. For example application **B** can be written not by me. But I still want to get such info.

Comment: Some mechanism keeps track of the locking and unlocking. Perhaps the same mechanism can provide the information that interests me. I do not claim this, but I hope for such an opportunity is existing.

Comment: "Some mechanism keeps track of the lock and its removal". Looks like `FileSystemWatcher` but if the FileStream is still open, I would go to the inter process communication and notify A that the lock ended.

Comment: @bradbury9 I know about it. But it notifies about the file editing without detailed info about what its chunk was edited.

Comment: Just inter comm and write in the message the filename, the offset, and the size of data written/modified

Comment: @bradbury9 what is *inter comm*?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a [Memory-Mapped File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) in your context? It might also help a lot in concurrent read/write operations across processes.