# Process.Start() passing the same argument multiple times?

Tags: c#

I have the following code (below), it starts a game on steam and passes one argument into it. Then the game connects to the multiplayer server, it works, however, I would like to know if there is a way to pass the same argument without opening the same program again and again.

I tried to use a loop (while), however, It didn't quite work because Process.Start() also launched the same program multiple times.

```
    private void JoinS3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string arg = "-connect=164.132.202.63:2302";
        Process.Start(FileData.GetSteamFolderPath, arg);
    }
```

Is there any other way to pass an argument into already opened process?

Comment: Your program needs an API of some sort.  There are a multitude of ways to do that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147.  There's some talk there about inter-process communication which may help you.

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/528652

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start is similar to an double-click on an exe-file.

You can pass arguments when you start a program. If the program is running, it has to read those additional inputs somehow.

A Simple Example-Game:

```
public class MyGame
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) // Here our Exe-Args are delivered to our program..
    {
        // Some dummycode to show what is done with your Args..
        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            string server = args.Where(a => a.StartsWith("-connect")).Select(s => s.Split(':').Last()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (server != null)
                ConnectToServer(server); // when starting with a "-connect" your game is stuck in this method.
        }

        // this will not be executed, because we are alread in the game, after "ConnectToServer()"
        ShowGameIntro();
        StartMainMenu();
    }
}
```

If you run this "game" with "-connect:...", the program will be "stuck" within the function "ConnectToServer()". It will not ask you for more arguments. Now the game is in charge doing things.
The game can ask the user for inputs, by listening to keyboard or mouse, but you can't force it to do so. And those inputs don't have to to anything with start arguments accepted when starting a game.

Most games have a console. There you could drop some commands.

Example Counter-Strike:
If you are on a Sever, you can open the console by pressing ^ and type those commands:

```
connect 192.168.0.1
disconnect
connect 192.168.0.1
disconnect
connect 192.168.0.1
disconnect
```

This would do what you want to do. If this is what you want to do, you should read about how to script for your game. After this you should ask yourself how to send those commands. But this is another question ;-)