# Send a message to already running WPF process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF and winform application both in C#. I invoke wpf app from winform app by using

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\wpfapp.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = data; //string result data from webservice;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

This is ok and i am able to run the wpf ui from winform with the parameters that has been sent as arguments. But now i have a problem. now i want to update the message in the running wpf window.

Already the wpf window is run and showing the message. Later i want to send another message to that same wpf window.
how we can achieve that ?

```
if (ProgramIsRunning(exepath))
{
    // here we need to add the code to send message to the same wpf window.
}
else
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\wpfapp.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = data; // string result data from webservice;
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Look at this post: [What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro) maybe it can help you out.

Comment: I think msmq is arguably simpler than pipes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like pipes as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro), you can host simple REST server using [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) in your WPF app and use something like [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to communicate with it.

Example message listener application:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:1234");
        var nancyHost = new NancyHost(baseUri);
        nancyHost.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(-1);
    }
}
public class SimpleRestModule : NancyModule {
    public SimpleRestModule() {
        Get["/Message"] = (args) => {
            return "Hello from server";
        };

        Post["/Message"] = (args) => {
            var receivedMessage = Request.Body.AsString();
            return "Message received";
        };
    }
}
```

Example message sender application:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:1234/Message", new StringContent("Test message")).Result;
    }
}
```