# Update WPF Label control's text/Content property from Winform application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am running 2 applications. one is a wpf windows application and another is a winform application. Winform calls the wpf project like this :

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Process myProcess = new Process();
       myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Wpf.exe";
       myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "hi how are you";
       myProcess.Start();
    }
```

The wpf app starts and shows a window with a label displays "hi how are you".
Later i want to update that label's text with "i am fine here" from winform application.

Any idea of how it can be done ? any help would be much appreciated.

How we can update the wpf label's text/Content from winform application (Both are two different exe projects) ???

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro

Comment: Also. A wpf label is actually a contentcontrol and has no text property. It has a content property. The equivalent to a winform label is TextBlock.