# What service use for real time communication between winforms

Tags: c#, .net, real-time

I want to create communication between multiple winform forms. I will have multiple forms from different projects. Every form can run and can be opened separately. But when they are opened they will look for each other and connect together.

I was thinking about simple TCP client/server but then I found signalR and socket.io. Now I'm not sure what to use. I will be sending json string.

Preferably I want to use local host communication.

Answer (score 1):

The forms you're mentioning will be in different processes (launched via different application executables), right?

If so, then any of the multiple mechanisms of inter-process communication should work, but the exact choice would depend on your requirements. Some ideas:

1. [Anonymous / named pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipe-operations)
2. WCF
3. Queuing mechanism where one process puts messages on a queue (e.g. in an SQLite database) and other consumes the messages (although it might not meet your "real-time" requirement)

Please consider googling for *inter-process communication* for more details. Also, this question and its answers give some overview of possible approaches: [What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro)

Comment: Thank you. Yes they are in different processes. I also look at wcf but I read it's not the best solution. I will look at the pipes.