# Sharing configuration values between different BackgroundServices .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .NET Core console application that I am running as a Windows Service in .NET Core 2.1. I will end up having multiple `BackgroundService` worker classes that will end up doing web calls. Some of these web calls rely on Authentication tokens that are fetch from their own `AuthTokenWorker` `BackgroundService`. I plan on saving those tokens within one worker class and sharing the value with the other worker classes.

How do I do that? Can I use `.ConfigureAppConfiguration` and use an in-memory collection? If I update a token in that configuration from one Worker, will the others using the same configuration through DI receive the updated value? Is doing that method thread safe?

In the past, I used a generic `static Configuration` class with a `ConcurrentDictionary` and just saved/fetched values from different classes, but I am new to .NET Core and want to know the appropriate way to achieve this.

eg.

`Program.cs`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, serviceCollection) =>
        {
            serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<SClient>();
            serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<DClient>();
            serviceCollection.AddHostedService<SWorker>();
            serviceCollection.AddHostedService<DWorker>();
        }).UseWindowsService();
```

}

`SWorker.cs`

I want to use the public property within `DWorker.cs`

```
public SClient(ILogger<STSTokenClient> logger, HttpClient client)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _client = client;
}

public SToken Token { get; internal set;}
```

Since I need an object to reference the property, can I inject it through the Constructor?

`DWorker.cs`

```
public DWorker(ILogger<DWorker> logger, SWorker sWorker,
    DClient dClient)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _sWorker = sWorker;
    _dClient = dClient;
}


protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    ...
    var token = await _dClient.FetchTokenAsync(_sWorker.Token);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to have a shared memory between these Background services? Like a Redis memory storage where you could store and retrieve in memory data.

Comment: @Bruno I'm looking for something that can be shared between these background services that's already provided by .NET.

Comment: then you should consider interprocess communication, as explained in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro But I personally would create a webapi and use it as a "layer" of communication would be the simplest way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I plan on saving those tokens within one worker class and sharing the value with the other worker classes.

Mutating configuration *might* work, but that's an odd way to approach this problem. The more natural approach would be to use something like [`IMemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) with well-known keys.

Note that the `GetOrCreate` and `GetOrCreateAsync` extension methods for `IMemoryCache` are *not* atomic. If you want an async-compatible "refresh this token, but if it's already being refreshed then share that refresh request" kind of operation, then you'll need to build that yourself. If you need that, I have an `AsyncCache` that can help.

Comment: This sounds like it'll solve my issue, what's your `AsyncCache` details?

Comment: [My `AsyncCache` is in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/39a2cd0aa3c705a984a4dbbea8275fe9). It's not fully tested and may be incomplet and inkorrect.